How to programmatically detect if a path is a ZFS snapshot?
All ZFS snapshots have paths like "/mount/point/path/.zfs/snapshot/NameOfSnapshot", but not all paths that can conceivably contain "/.zfs/snapshot/" are necessarily ZFS snapshots. How can I detect that a path is (or is contained in) a ZFS snapshot? Is there a fast way to detect it, either through API calls or by invoking the zfs command-line utility in a mode intended to be parsed by other programs, or do I have to enumerate snapshots and compare? I guess if it's the latter, I can at least defer enumerating snapshots until I know the path contains the substring "/.zfs/snapshot/"...
UPDATE: This needs to be very efficient. Let's say I have a million paths and I need to exclude those that are in ZFS snapshots. And, the million paths are not arriving in one function call, so simply enumerating the mounts once isn't a simple solution.
My application is written in C#, but knowing how to do this from C would be adaptable.

/mount/point/path?  It appears to me that you could check if that's the mount point of a ZFS filesystem.  Then verify that ZFS won't allow creation of a directory called .zfs in the root directory of a ZFS file system.

Mm, so I need to enumerate mounts? There isn't some sort of efficient stat-like thing I can do on the path directly?

I don't understand why this was closed as not being programming-related.
